# Template class member function instatitation

Tags: c++, templates

The Standard `N4296::14.7.1/1` says:

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
>   the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the
>   definitions, default arguments, or exception-specifications of the
>   class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations,
>   static data members and member templates;

Let's then consider the following code:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    void foo(){ }
};

A<int> a; //Implicit instantiation here

int main(){ }
```

So, when the template is being implicitly instantiated it actually intstantiated in a class which doesn't have any member function, because we've not used it.  Is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class has a member function that is declared but not yet defined.

This is allowed in non-template classes too; a (non-virtual) member function only needs a definition if you use it.

So in your template the function declaration must be valid when instantiated, but the function  body is not yet required to work.

Comment: Couldn't you provide a normative reference? I'd like to make sure about how it works more formally...